# Replace the div content

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am testing the difference between the real DOM and Virtual DOM. So I make an example with `setInterval` to render the `div` show time per second. But I don't know how to replace the content of `div#real-dom` each time.

```js
function replaceWithVDOM() {
    let element = (
      <div>
          <h2>What time is it? - With ReactJS</h2>
          <h3>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h3>
      </div>
    )
    ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById("root"))
}

function replaceWithRDOM() {
    let element = `
        <div>
            <h2>What time is it? - Without ReactJS</h2>
            <h3>It is ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h3>
        </div>`

    // Update the div#real-dom with the elemet here
}

setInterval(replaceWithVDOM, 1000);
//setInterval(replaceWithRDOM, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
-----------------------
<div id="real-dom"></div>
```

Any suggestion?

UPDATED:

Thanks for the help. Now I can see the difference between them. 
I made it at [codepen](https://codepen.io/tamdc/pen/bZayPo?editors=1010), for who want to see the diff (chrome dev tools)

Comment: i think can do with simple replacement `document.getElementById("real-dom").innerHTML =new Date().toLocaleTimeString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("real-dom").innerHTML = element;
```

This is dangerous and should only be used as a test, never for anything in production.

For the purposes of a test, you will likely see better performance from the DOM APIs if you learn how to safely create elements without innerHTML, however. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document, specifically `createElement`, `createTextNode`, and `appendChild`.